# Android re-enable a disabled App upon installation of update

Tags: android, components, reinstall

Im currently disabling an application via
    setApplicationEnabledSetting(String, int, int)

The application is actually disabling itself.
I would expect upon re-installation of the app, the app would re-enable itself, however this isnt the case.

Is there a particular setting required in the manifest to make this work.
(Ive tried setting enabled=true)

Thanks

Im currently disabling all components apart from a broadcast receiver and am trying to catch the installation process to re-enable all the other components again. Which is nasty to say the least

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to listen to package installation broadcasts and take action accordingly.

- Listen to [`Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) in your broadcast receiver.
- If the newly added package is yours, enable the other components.

#### Example

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name =".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Receiver:**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(action)) {
            final boolean replacing = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false);
            final String packageName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
            if (replacing && "my.package.name".equals(packageName)) {
                // Re-enable the other components
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the post. It doesnt directly answer the question, as this requires atleast one component to remain running, but it  does provide the desired result. Also it would be best to use android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED or android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.

Ill leave the question opened for a few days before I accept an answer.

Comment: _It doesnt directly answer the question, as this requires atleast one component to remain running_ -- No additional component is required, you can the above filters to your existing broadcast receiver: _Im currently disabling all components **apart from a broadcast receiver**_