# how to distingguish "disable" or "enable" of pre-installed system apps on Android 4.0 or higher?

Tags: android, android-intent, system

As we know, from Android 4.0 users can disable/enable pre-installed system apps.

Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED can be received by register broadcast receiver, but I can NOT distingguish app disable or enable.

My question is how to distingguish them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code:

```
    public void checkEnable() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("FULL PACKAGENAME", "Full ComponentName(activity/service)");
        int ret = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting (cn);

        if(ret != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) {
            Log.w(TAG, "We are disabled by someone...");
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Robin. I tried "Context.getPackageManager().getApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName)", it works!

Answer (score -1):

So Are you rooted, Unless you are rooted you can't disable a third party app, since your app is also a third party app to the system, Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679796/android-re-enable-a-disabled-app-upon-installation-of-update)

It contains something useful for you